# how to center a div inside the header from the top

Tags: html, css

I have a header it contains two divs [ left div and right div ] and offset 4-cols before them . What i want is to make the right div at the middle of the header .

```css
.header 
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 15px;
}


.header .left img { width: 90%; }
.header .right > div { display: inline-block; }
.header .right span { color: #0095AE }
.header .right > span:first-child { font-size: 22px; }
.header .right > div p
 {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #0095AE
}

.header .right > div p:first-child { text-align: right }
```

```html
        <div class="header">

              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ">
                    <div class="left">
                            <img class ="logo" src="images/logo.png">
                    </div>

              </div>


                <div class="col-md-4 ">

                        <div class="right"> 

                            <span>By</span> 
                            <img src="images/crescent.png" >
                            <div> 
                                <p> الهلال الأحمر الأردني  </p>
                                <p>  JORDAN RED  CRESCENT </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

This how it looks  ,  I tried padding 50% but doesn't work as what i want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rthsl.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how exactly you want it. But from what i understand ,you can make use of display:flex here

check this snippet

```css
.header {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.col-md-4 {
  display: flex;
}
.col-md-4:last-child {}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ">
      <div class="left">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 ">

      <div class="right">

        <span>By</span> 
        <img src="images/crescent.png">
        <div>
          <p>الهلال الأحمر الأردني</p>
          <p>JORDAN RED CRESCENT</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps